# How should I use reference with setcounter{lstlisting}{0}?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, listings

I specified in my `lstlisting` both caption and label. Also before every section I use:

```
\setcounter{lstlisting}{0}
```

My listing from PDF view looks like: Listing 4.1.2 SomeCaption

When I am using `\ref{lst:someKey}` it does not work properly. I mean it links to other listing than it should (before suitable place). For example 4.1.4 instead of 4.2.4.

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with that? Here is a copy of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, 
    linktoc=all
}
\lstset{language=Java,
captionpos=b, 
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize, 
numbers=left,
aboveskip=20pt,
belowskip=20pt,
xleftmargin=40pt}
\author{Marcin}
\title{Latex problem}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}
\chapter{Chap First}
\section{Section first}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur congue faucibus scelerisque. Proin urna leo, tempor quis imperdiet quis, auctor nec purus. Donec ultricies ligula sapien, nec consequat enim suscipit quis. Nulla rhoncus felis dui, et volutpat enim suscipit varius. Morbi non sem felis. Fusce ullamcorper lacus nunc, et vehicula metus suscipit ut. Donec et iaculis mi, at mollis turpis. Fusce mattis pretium rhoncus. Aenean auctor urna id consectetur porttitor. Vivamus lectus elit, mollis eget tempus vitae, tempor a erat. Suspendisse sed felis non augue porttitor lobortis nec eget nunc. Aliquam id sollicitudin ante. Sed sodales lectus a augue porttitor, et iaculis nisi iaculis. Aliquam varius quis est non viverra. Aenean eget arcu eget sapien posuere rhoncus. 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test1}, label={lst:test1}]
if(a==0){
    //body
}
\end{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur congue faucibus scelerisque. Proin urna leo, tempor quis imperdiet quis, auctor nec purus. Donec ultricies ligula sapien, nec consequat enim suscipit quis. Nulla rhoncus felis dui, et volutpat enim suscipit varius. Morbi non sem felis. Fusce ullamcorper lacus nunc, et vehicula metus suscipit ut. Donec et iaculis mi, at mollis turpis. Fusce mattis pretium rhoncus. Aenean auctor urna id consectetur porttitor. Vivamus lectus elit, mollis eget tempus vitae, tempor a erat. Suspendisse sed felis non augue porttitor lobortis nec eget nunc. Aliquam id sollicitudin ante. Sed sodales lectus a augue porttitor, et iaculis nisi iaculis. Aliquam varius quis est non viverra. Aenean eget arcu eget sapien posuere rhoncus. 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test2}, label={lst:test2}]
if(a!=0){
    //body
}
\end{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur congue faucibus scelerisque. Proin urna leo, tempor quis imperdiet quis, auctor nec purus. Donec ultricies ligula sapien, nec consequat enim suscipit quis. Nulla rhoncus felis dui, et volutpat enim suscipit varius. Morbi non sem felis. Fusce ullamcorper lacus nunc, et vehicula metus suscipit ut. Donec et iaculis mi, at mollis turpis. Fusce mattis pretium rhoncus. Aenean auctor urna id consectetur porttitor. Vivamus lectus elit, mollis eget tempus vitae, tempor a erat. Suspendisse sed felis non augue porttitor lobortis nec eget nunc. Aliquam id sollicitudin ante. Sed sodales lectus a augue porttitor, et iaculis nisi iaculis. Aliquam varius quis est non viverra. Aenean eget arcu eget sapien posuere rhoncus. 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test3}, label={lst:test3}]
if(a>0){
    //body
}
\end{lstlisting}

\setcounter{lstlisting}{0}
\section{Section second}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur congue faucibus scelerisque. Proin urna leo, tempor quis imperdiet quis, auctor nec purus. Donec ultricies ligula sapien, nec consequat enim suscipit quis. Nulla rhoncus felis dui, et volutpat enim suscipit varius. Morbi non sem felis. Fusce ullamcorper lacus nunc, et vehicula metus suscipit ut. Donec et iaculis mi, at mollis turpis. Fusce mattis pretium rhoncus. Aenean auctor urna id consectetur porttitor. Vivamus lectus elit, mollis eget tempus vitae, tempor a erat. Suspendisse sed felis non augue porttitor lobortis nec eget nunc. Aliquam id sollicitudin ante. Sed sodales lectus a augue porttitor, et iaculis nisi iaculis. Aliquam varius quis est non viverra. Aenean eget arcu eget sapien posuere rhoncus. 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test4}, label={lst:test4}]
if(a==0){
    //body
}
\end{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur congue faucibus scelerisque. Proin urna leo, tempor quis imperdiet quis, auctor nec purus. Donec ultricies ligula sapien, nec consequat enim suscipit quis. Nulla rhoncus felis dui, et volutpat enim suscipit varius. Morbi non sem felis. Fusce ullamcorper lacus nunc, et vehicula metus suscipit ut. Donec et iaculis mi, at mollis turpis. Fusce mattis pretium rhoncus. Aenean auctor urna id consectetur porttitor. Vivamus lectus elit, mollis eget tempus vitae, tempor a erat. Suspendisse sed felis non augue porttitor lobortis nec eget nunc. Aliquam id sollicitudin ante. Sed sodales lectus a augue porttitor, et iaculis nisi iaculis. Aliquam varius quis est non viverra. Aenean eget arcu eget sapien posuere rhoncus. 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test5}, label={lst:test5}]
if(a!=0){
    //body
}
\end{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur congue faucibus scelerisque. Proin urna leo, tempor quis imperdiet quis, auctor nec purus. Donec ultricies ligula sapien, nec consequat enim suscipit quis. Nulla rhoncus felis dui, et volutpat enim suscipit varius. Morbi non sem felis. Fusce ullamcorper lacus nunc, et vehicula metus suscipit ut. Donec et iaculis mi, at mollis turpis. Fusce mattis pretium rhoncus. Aenean auctor urna id consectetur porttitor. Vivamus lectus elit, mollis eget tempus vitae, tempor a erat. Suspendisse sed felis non augue porttitor lobortis nec eget nunc. Aliquam id sollicitudin ante. Sed sodales lectus a augue porttitor, et iaculis nisi iaculis. Aliquam varius quis est non viverra. Aenean eget arcu eget sapien posuere rhoncus. 
Sth interesting happend in listing \ref{lst:test5}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test6}, label={lst:test6}]
if(a>0){
    //body
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of manually setting the `lstlisting` counter to 0 before every section, you should provide the means for LaTeX to do this automatically. Also, it's not really clear *why* you're getting an incorrect reference. Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that duplicates your problem. This should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. We need to be able to copy-and-paste the code, compile it locally and reproduce your problem. That's the only way we can start evaluating the problem and provide a suitable solution.

Comment: I prepared an example. You can easily copy it from: http://wklej.org/id/1382107/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that replicates your problem (without any extra bits):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}}
\begin{document}
\section{Section first}
Reference to Test2 is Listing~\ref{lst:test2}.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test1}, label={lst:test1}]
if(a==0){
    //body
}
\end{lstlisting}

\setcounter{lstlisting}{0}
\section{Section second}
Reference to Test1 is Listing~\ref{lst:test1}.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test2}, label={lst:test2}]
if(a==0){
    //body
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

You will have noticed in the `.log` a reference to

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same 
  identifier (name{lstlisting.1}) has been already used, 
  duplicate ignored
```

This implies that a hyperlink destination jump has a duplicate identifier to jump to, so that's why the jump occurs to the incorrect location. Despite this, the reference is still correct.

The problem with the incorrect hyperlink is solved by doing two things:

1. Do not reset the `lstlisting` counter back to zero at the start of every section (*i.e.*, remove `\setcounter{lstlisting}{0}`). This is error-prone, and also causes confusion for [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref);
2. Add to your preamble

   ```
   \usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr
   \AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}}
   ```

   This resets the `lstlisting` counter with every new `\section` and also prepends `\thesection` to `\thelstlisting` (so you don't even have to do `\AtBeginDocument{\thelstlisting}{\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}`).

Comment: Thanks, Werner! I have been using LaTeX for a few months and it is a beginning of this journey, so each tip is precious.